# HTML Stopping code from repeating (functions)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have some HTML code for a box that has text located inside. I do not want to repeat the code and would like to put it in some sort of function. This way I can create an argument that can put the text in the box. Is there anyway of doing this in like HTML itself, JavaScript or PHP?

Comment: HTML is only a markup language. The task you describe can be done with either JavaScript or PHP.

Comment: html is not a programming language. it can't "do" anything. it has no programming capabilities whatsoever. so yes, you'll have to use something else, like php or JS.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to do it with php. In order to run php, you need to have a server set up. If this is just on your computer, you can do this by downloading WAMP (if you are on Windows), LAMP (if Linux), or MAMP (if Mac). It is free an can get you started. If you have any questions on this, please feel free to ask.

Here is an example function within html:

```
<?php

function doSomething($someVariable) {
    return $someVariable + 1;
}

?>

<html>
<body>

   <p> The number after 3 is <?php echo doSomething(3); ?></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Notice whenever I am using php I have to start it with `<?php`, then, when I am going back to html and ending the php, I have to end it with `?>`.

Comment: How can I make a function that has html code in it in PHP?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean by this question. You can store html in a variable. For example: `$someHTML = "<p>This is a paragraph on my page</p>";`. Then, whenever you want to print to the page you can just type in `echo $someHTML;`. If that doesn't answer your question, please explain further.

Comment: @StevenYoung this is a great answer. However, depending on where the text is coming from, JavaScript could do the same thing without any install pre-requisites.

Answer (score 0):

`HTML is a language used to describe to a browser how to display text and other objects in a browser window.` It is not a programming language. HTML works on a client computer (the system on which the page is being viewed).

You can use some scripting language to create web pages written in HTML.

PHP is one option thar runs on the server system from which the page comes, and is a full-fledged programming language.

`Javascript that runs on browser, is a scripting language, used to complete the interactive and simple functions in a web page`,is also an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so easily with javascript.

```js
function updateInput(inputText) {
  var input = document.getElementById('testInput');
  input.value = inputText;
}
```

```html
<input id="testInput"></input>
<button onclick="updateInput('Hello World')">Update Textbox!</button>
```